# How To Find Duplicate and Update Values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

using this query:

```
SELECT ARCustomerCode,
       count(ARCustomerCode)
FROM customers
group by ARCustomerCode
having count(ARCustomerCode) > 1;
```

I am able to identify the number of rows where ARCustomerCode is not unique. How can I update each duplicate ARCustomerCode field by appending the unique row id?

Appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function to assign a ranking to each duplicate of "*ARCustomerCode*" values, then update only the records which have ranking > 1 (all duplicates) for each code.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ARCustomerCode ORDER BY <row_id_col>) AS rn
    FROM customers
)
UPDATE     customers
INNER JOIN cte 
        ON customers.<row_id_col> = cte.<row_id_col>
SET customers.ARCustomerCode = CONCAT(customers.ARCustomerCode, customers.<row_id_col>)
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: The field *id* is the primary key. I am a little confused on what I should remove in that situation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just updated the answer with this info. Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
select case 
  when lag(ARCustomerCode) over (order by ARCustomerCode) = ARCustomerCode
    then code + cast(row_number() over (partition by ARCustomerCodeorder by ARCustomerCode) as varchar(50))
  when lead(ARCustomerCode) over (order by ARCustomerCode) = ARCustomerCode
    then code + cast(row_number() over (partition by ARCustomerCodeorder by ARCustomerCode) as varchar(50))
  else ARCustomerCode 
end
```

It's even simpler if you don't need to append a number to the first instance of the dup.

```
select case 
  when lag(ARCustomerCode) over (order by ARCustomerCode) = ARCustomerCode
    then code + cast(row_number() over (partition by ARCustomerCodeorder by ARCustomerCode) as varchar(50))
  else ARCustomerCode 
end
```